# Each line from file as variable & run command with these variables

Tags: bash

What method can I use to write script for below task?

File hosts.txt has over one hundred different lines (hostnames).
Need to extract lines as variable(s) and run command with these variables.

File: hosts.txt:
*hostname1

hostname2

...

hostname100*

command with <$hostname1> inside
command with <$hostname2> inside
command with <$hostname...> inside
command with <$hostname100> inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```bash
while read host ; do 
    command param1 "$host" param2
done < hosts.txt
```

or `xargs`:

```bash
xargs -I% command param1 % param2 < hosts.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly something like can do the work:

```
while read i
do
command with $i
done < hosts.txt
```

This create loop over all the hostnames in `hosts.txt` and execute consecutively the command